# How to make an autocomplete text view using an array from Firestore using an Array Adapter

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I would like to know how to get data from an Array in Firestore and populate the data to an array adapter, which is a simple drop down item of one line(Custom Array Adapter). When the user gets to type information the Autocomplete Text View can do the job by recommending specific data. 
[This shows how to make an autocomplete locally with no connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSqsk.png)

[I am trying to get the data and populate it to an Array list but does not work using this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ABMT.png)

Comment: Show your code that you have tried so far

Comment: @pskink The problem is fetching the Array from Firestore and adding it to an Array Adapter. For instance i have a document that has an Array of Fruits. How should i get the Array from Firestore and add it to my ArrayAdapter so as to populate the examples of fruits to an Autocomplete Text View

Comment: @Androidenthu. I am lost a bit. Because some people are saying if i use a Map to get the Array from Firestore it returns an ArrayList.

Comment: @Androidenthu. Look at those images

Comment: sorry @Felix but its not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. What you want to bind to Autocomplete view ? Countries or cities